# Magento get customer telephone by sql

Tags: sql, magento

How to get customer's telephone by sql code,

Comment: Where do you want to get this? On what page? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Magento is based on EAV architectur
So if you take a look at eav_attribute table you'll see that telephone attribute is a varchar and the entity_type_id is 2 (it mean it's a customer address attribute)
You Sql request may look like :

```
select customer_address_entity_varchar.value from customer_address_entity_varchar
left join  customer_entity on customer_entity.entity_id = "your_customer_id"
left join  customer_address_entity on customer_address_entity.parent_id = customer_entity.entity_id
join eav_attribute on eav_attribute.attribute_code="telephone"
where customer_address_entity_varchar.attribute_id = eav_attribute.attribute_id
```